# magento 2 Change configuration value dynamically on certain condition

Tags: magento2, configuration

I required to change configuration values dynamically On certain condition.

Consider i need to change value of "Display Out of Stock Products" dynamically on certain condition.

I do not want to make changes by using plugin or observer where it is used.

Thanks

Comment: Why not plugin?

Comment: I mean we can use plugin for class "\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface" but do want to use plugin that return value or pass parameter of configuration like for execute function of class 'Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\AddStockDataToCollection" of $isFilterInStock parameter.

Comment: My concern here is where ever they check for configuration we need to write either plugin or observer to change its return type or change parameter value. So let's consider there are three class which check condition for display product of out of stock yes or no. we need to  create three  plugin or observer( it depends) which seems  lot of code need to write for just set configuration value on certain condition.